# Custom Laravel Pagination

Tags: laravel-4

I want to custom Laravel 4.2 pagination to something like this :

Old: 
`www.domain.com/lorem-ipsum?page=2`

New: 
`www.domain.com/lorem-ipsum-page2`

It is possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to specify it on your route definition:

Old:

```
Route::get('lorem-ipsum', function() {
    $page = Input::get['page'];
});
```

To:

```
Route::get('lorem-ipsum-page{page}', function($page) {
     // now page is as a parameter of this function, it is not necessary to get it from Input
});
```